# PHP save CSV file with UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

My php knowledge is limited, I am trying to export a table from mySQL into a CSV file that is saved to a set local location on the server. I have this working from some code I found, however I need to for the encoding of the CSV file to UTF-8, what do I add to this code to get it to do that please?

```
$myfile = fopen("geniusExportTable.csv", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $output);
fclose($myfile);
```

EDIT, I can use phpMyAdmin to export the table to CSV, Excel then imports the CSV into MS SQL and that works fine but I need to automate this process. I can get the file to export with PHP (CRON to schedule) but Excel seems to not read the same encoding which phpMyAdmin states as UTF-8 when using PHP. I need a way to get the file to save with the correct encoding please.

Comment: is mysqldump or mysqlexport command line function fit ? https://www.google.fr/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=mysqlexport&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=2cIaVe-xG8mFWNKpgJgJ#channel=fs&q=mysql+export&spell=1

Comment: to go further, the charset depends on the data you have in input. For example, if it's ISO, use utf8_encode(). Becareful of your connection charset to mysql (look at SET NAMES MySQL), you table / database / field charset. and becareful of the way you will visualize the csv (your IDE or text editor must be in UTF-8 too)

Comment: Its a specific table not the entire database I need. I have it all working apart from the correct encoding

Comment: so my 2nd comment can fit

Comment: Please see my edit above

Comment: What is the exact goal ? cause you can use mysqlexport or dump for only one table, or make in command line `mysql -u [USER] -p [DATABASE] -e "SELECT * FROM \`table\` > list.out` see also http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/

Comment: `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ...`